# SQl Server 2012 Creating New Server Registration Error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I recently installed SQL Server 2012, and I could connect to my default instance, but every time I created a new server registration, I get an error:

> TITLE: New Server Registration Testing the registered server failed.
>   Verify the server name, login credentials, and database, and then
>   click Test again.
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
>   (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53)
>
> The network path was not found

Comment: When you say you can connect, how are you connecting - just directly via the Object Explorer?

Comment: yes, I connect to object explorer.

Comment: For S&G's can you make sure the connection type on both is the same - e.g. if the OE connection uses TCP then ensure the Registered Server also uses TCP etc.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new into SQL, how do you check if both the connection is the same because I went to the SQL Configuration manager, I already check the TCP port is in default:1433. The issues I'm having is when I clicked on the View, Register Servers, and under the Database Engine, I right click the Local Server Groups to create a new Server Registration and input the name and once I press test, it give me the errors.

Comment: Both OE and a registered server should normally use the same defaults, but in your case perhaps not. On the registered server connection hit the tab marked "Connection Properties" and modify the "Network Protocol" to match the same protocol you had with the OE dialog when you press the "Options>>" button there. Also, I assume it's a given you are using the same username\password (if Sql authentication) as well

Comment: Yeah, I checked the OE network protocol, it is in default. I also checked my registered servers network protocol is in default too, but I still received the error. I used the the window authentication for my OE and registered server.

Comment: That may be the issue - may be. Change BOTH to TCP and try again. Ensure BOTH use the same protocol (NOT the default). If TCP doesnt work then Named Pipes then Shared memory.

Comment: I have changed Both to TCP/IP, Shared Memory, and Name Piped, I still received the errors

Comment: So did all them work for OE but yet all fail for the registered server?

Comment: yep, I could connect to the OE using all the TCP/Ip, Shared Memory, and Named Piped, but the registered server all failed.